# How can I make my PHP application more object-oriented?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, design-patterns

I have been developing PHP web applications for a few years. I almost always use an MVC pattern (usually with CodeIgniter), but I feel like most of the time I am just using classes to structure my code rather than really using objects.

I have yet to see a need to implement any traditional design patterns (Factory, Command, Decorator, etc.). Is this just the nature of CI? or MVC? or Web applications? or PHP?

Is there a way (or a need) to implement any of these patterns in a CI application? Do other frameworks make that more feasible? Or, is it just unnecessary for MVC applications?

Comment: that's a problem most mvc frameworks face sooner or later. In the Ruby world the same discussion happens for Rails and how it breaks the oo patterns in ruby.

Comment: This is question is to broad to answer in the format used here at StackOverflow. Do you have a concrete code example that could be restructured by using design patterns?

Comment: Obviously a framework with more powerful concepts of Object Programming would be http://agiletoolkit.org/

Comment: Hmm. It's kind of an open-ended question, but, while there is A LOT of documentation on how to learn the ABC's of programming PHP procedurally, there is very little documentation and examples on the how's and why's of using advanced OO techniques.  The question has some merit.